# How to stop Iframe (video) after modal close?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I met some problems in my code, I find some solutions in this forum but somehow it doesn't help me. So maybe you will find how to solve it. I need to stop the video after closing it with the cross icon and also after clicking on the modal. Also, it will be cool if this video starts from beginning after it opens again.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "BebasNeue";
  src: url("fonts/BebasNeue.otf");
}

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
 -moz-font-smoothing:antialiased;
 -o-font-smoothing:antialiased;
 font-smoothing: antialiased;
 text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;
}

::selection {
  background: #f3df4b; /* WebKit/Blink Browsers */
}
::-moz-selection {
  background: #f3df4b; /* Gecko Browsers */
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #f8f8f8;  /* fallback for old browsers */
}
h1{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'BebasNeue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 6rem;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
}
h2{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'BebasNeue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
p{
  font-family: 'BebasNeue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  color: #111;
}
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}
.push {
  height: 50px;
}
/*/////////menu////////////*/
header{
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu_box{
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
}
.menu_box_logo{
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
.menu_box_ul {
  float: right;
  padding: 40px 0 20px 20px;
}
.menu_box_ul a {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'BebasNeue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
}
.menu_box_ul a:hover {
  color: #F3DF4B;
}
.menu_box_ul .icon {
  display: none;
}
.menu_box_ul_more{
  display: none;
  top: 40px;
}
.menu_box_ul_more a {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'BebasNeue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
}
.menu_box_ul_more a:hover {
  color: white;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 826px) {
  .menu_box_ul_more{
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 826px) {
  .menu_box_ul_more.show{
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 826px) {
  .menu_box_ul a {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu_box_ul a.icon,
  .menu_box_ul a.language {
    display: inline;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 826px){
  .menu_box_ul_more.show .icon{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .menu_box_ul_more.show{
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 110px;
  }
  .menu_box_ul_more.show a{
    display: block;
  }
}
#a_checked{
  color: #F3DF4B;
}
.menu_icon{
  display: none;
}
/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.container{
    margin-top: 100px;
}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1000;
}
/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
/*/////////index////////////*/
.logo{
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
}
.text{
  display:table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align:center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 120px 20px 0px 20px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
.text1{
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.text2{
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.text2 .h2{
  font-family: 'BebasNeue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
}
.text3{
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.about_button{
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  line-height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 500px;
}
.text3_span{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
}
.about_read_watch{
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.text4_span{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
}
.button{
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #F3DF4B;
  border: 2px solid #F3DF4B;
  border-radius: 999px;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-right: 1.44em;
  padding-right: calc(1.44em - .2em);
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-left: 1.44em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
.button2{
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #F3DF4B;
  border: 2px solid #F3DF4B;
  border-radius: 999px;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-right: 1.44em;
  padding-right: calc(1.44em - .2em);
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-left: 1.44em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.button3{
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #F3DF4B;
  border: 2px solid #F3DF4B;
  border-radius: 999px;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-right: 1.44em;
  padding-right: calc(1.44em - .2em);
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-left: 1.44em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.button:hover,
.button2:hover,
.button3:hover{
  color: #000;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  -webkit-transition: color 500ms ease-in-out, border-color 170ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: color 500ms ease-in-out, border-color 170ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: color 500ms ease-in-out, border-color 170ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: color 500ms ease-in-out, border-color 170ms ease-in-out;
}
@media (max-width:545px) {
  .text1 h1{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
  .text1{
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .text2{
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
    .text2 h2{
    font-size: 2rem;
    }
  .text3{
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .text{
    padding: 50px 20px 0px 20px;
  }
}
.imglog{
  margin-top: 70px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 190.5px;
}
@media (max-width: 470px) {
  .imglog{
    width: 250px;
    height: 95.25px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 585px) {
  .button3{
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 390px) {
  .button2{
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}
/*/////////footer////////////*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css);

.footer {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.col-lg-6 .offset-lg-2 {
    width: 260px;
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.col-lg-6 .offset-lg-2 ul{
    padding:0;
    list-style: none;
}
.social-icon {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.875rem;
}
.social-icons{
    margin-bottom: -1rem;
}
.social-icons li {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline;
}
.social-icons a {
    color: rgb(234, 234, 234);
    text-decoration: none;
}
.fa-facebook {
    padding:10px 14px;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition: .5s;
    color: #000;
}
.fa-facebook:hover {
    background-color: #3d5b99;
}
.fa-youtube {
    padding:10px 14px;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition: .5s;
    color: #000;
}
.fa-youtube:hover {
    background-color: #e64a41;
}
.fa-linkedin {
    padding:10px 14px;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition: .5s;
    color: #000;
}
.fa-linkedin:hover {
    background-color: #0073a4;
}
.fa-instagram {
    padding:10px 14px;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition: .5s;
    color: #000;
}
.fa-instagram:hover {
    background-color: #9b6954;
}

/*/////////work.html file////////////*/

.col-lg-5.col-md-12 a{
    text-decoration-line: none;
}

#div_box_video{
    width: 650px;
    height: 550px;
    background-image: url(/./honey/rusne.jpg);
      -ms-background-position-x: center;
  -ms-background-position-y: bottom;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-size: cover;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#div_box_video img{
    z-index: 3;
}

#shadow_box{
    position: relative;
    width: 650px;
    height: 550px;
    background-color: rgba(137, 137, 137, 0.56);
    z-index: 10;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(28, 28, 28);
}
#shadow_box:hover{
    background-color: rgba(137, 137, 137, 0.9);
}

#popupBoxOnePosition{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: none;
  z-index: 101;
}
#popupBoxTwoPosition{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: none;
  z-index: 101;
}
#popupBoxThreePosition{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: none;
  z-index: 101;
}
#popupBoxFourPosition{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: none;
  z-index: 101;
}
.login-html{
 width:70%;
 height:85%;
 position:absolute;
 padding:90px 70px 50px 70px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 7.5%;
  left: 15%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 0;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#forphone2{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;
}

@media (max-width:1298px) {
  .sign-in-htm iframe{
    height: 550px;
  }
    .login-html{
    width: 90%;
    left: 5%;
  }
}

@media (max-width:1000px) {
  .sign-in-htm iframe{
    height: 400px;
  }
  .login-html{
    width: 90%;
    left: 5%;
    top: 15%;
  }
}

@media (max-width:780px) {
  .sign-in-htm iframe{
    height: 300px;
  }
  .login-html{
    width: 100%;
    left: 0%;
  }
}
@media (max-width:550px) {
  .sign-in-htm iframe{
    height: 300px;
  }
  .login-html{
    width: 100%;
    left: 0%;
    top: 20%;
    padding:90px 35px 50px 35px;
  }
}
@media (max-width:450px) {
  .sign-in-htm iframe{
    height: 200px;
  }
  .login-html{
    width: 100%;
    left: 0%;
    top: 20%;
    padding:90px 15px 50px 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="lt-LT"
    xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"
    xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
  <script async src=""></script>
  <script>

  </script>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../img/favicon.ico" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <meta name="google-site-verification" content="" />
 <title>Honey agency | Video Production</title>
  <meta name="google-site-verification" content="" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <meta name="description" itemprop="description" content="Main agiency &quot;Video Production&quot; services:  video promotion, video creation, video" />
  <meta name="keywords" itemprop="keywords" content="video promotion, video creation, video" />
  <link rel="canonical" href="http://thehoney.lt/" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Begining"/>
  <meta property="og:description" content="[fullwidth backgroundcolor=&quot;&quot; backgroundimage=&quot;&quot; backgroundrepeat=&quot;no-repeat&quot; backgroundposition=&quot;top left&quot; backgroundattachment=&quot;scroll&quot; bordersize=&quot;1px&quot; bordercolor=&quot;&quot; paddingTop=&quot;&quot; paddingBottom=&quot;20&quot;]Make your story sweet as honey!Agiency &quot;VIDEO PRODUCTION SERVICES&quot; -  is"/>
  <meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://thehoney.lt/"/>
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="VIDEO PRODUCTION SERVICES"/>
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://thehoney.lt/img/honey_logo_transparent_croped.png"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css?v=1.1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    
  <div id="popupBoxOnePosition" class="modal">
    <div class="login-html">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('popupBoxOnePosition').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal1">&times;</span>
        <div class="login-form">
          <div class="sign-in-htm">
            <iframe width="100%" height="700px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ttt8U6teiH0?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="popupBoxTwoPosition" class="modal">
    <div class="login-html">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('popupBoxTwoPosition').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal2">&times;</span>
        <div class="login-form">
          <div class="sign-in-htm">
            <iframe width="100%" height="700" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/x-3BnCklSuE?showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="popupBoxThreePosition" class="modal">
    <div class="login-html">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('popupBoxThreePosition').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal3">&times;</span>
        <div class="login-form">
          <div class="sign-in-htm">
            <iframe width="100%" height="700px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ttt8U6teiH0?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    
  <div id="popupBoxFourPosition" class="modal">
    <div class="login-html">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('popupBoxFourPosition').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal4">&times;</span>
        <div class="login-form">
          <div class="sign-in-htm">
            <iframe width="100%" height="700px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ttt8U6teiH0?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <div class="menu_box" id="menu_box">
        <div class="menu_box_logo">
          <a href="../"><img class="imglogo" style="width: 250px; height:95,25px;" src="../img/honey_logo_transparent_croped.png" alt="Honey logo"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu_box_ul" id="myTopnav">
          <a href="." id="a_checked">Our work</a>
          <a href="../about/">Who we are</a>
          <a href="../contacts/">Contact us</a>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu_box_ul_more" id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="." id="a_checked">Our work</a>
          <a href="../about/">Who we are</a>
          <a href="../contacts/">Contact us</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-bottom: 70px; width:100%;">
      <div class="row justify-content-center" style="width:100%; margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0;">
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12" id="forphone">
            <a id="forphone2" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('popupBoxOnePosition').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">
                <div class="col-12" id="div_box_video" style="padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;">
                   <div class="col-12" id="shadow_box">
                           <h1 style="color: #f8f8f8; text-align: center; position: relative; top: 50%; -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); transform: translateY(-50%);">Rusnytė<p >Rusnytės projektas</p></h1>
                           
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12" id="forphone">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('popupBoxTwoPosition').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">
                <div class="col-12" id="div_box_video" style="padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;">
                   <div class="col-12" id="shadow_box">
                           <h1 style="color: #f8f8f8; text-align: center; position: relative; top: 50%; -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); transform: translateY(-50%);">Rusnytė<p >Rusnytės projektas</p></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row justify-content-center" style="width:100%; margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0;">
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12" >
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('popupBoxThreePosition').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">
                <div class="col-12" id="div_box_video" style="padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;">
                   <div class="col-12" id="shadow_box">
                           <h1 style="color: #f8f8f8; text-align: center; position: relative; top: 50%; -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); transform: translateY(-50%);">Rusnytė<p >Rusnytės projektas</p></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12" >
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('popupBoxFourPosition').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">
                <div class="col-12" id="div_box_video" style="padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;">
                   <div class="col-12" id="shadow_box">
                           <h1 style="color: #f8f8f8; text-align: center; position: relative; top: 50%; -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); transform: translateY(-50%);">Rusnytė<p >Rusnytės projektas</p></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      
      <div class="raw" style="margin-top: 70px;">
        <div class="about_read_watch">
          <span class="text4_span">
            <input type="button" class="button" onclick="location.href='../contacts';" value="Contact Us"/>
          </span>
      </div>
    </div>
      
    <div class="push"></div>
  </div>

  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="social">
      <div class="footer-social-icons">
        <ul class="social-icons">
          <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/Honey-Media-247807789328138/" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/11763547/" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/thehoney_media/" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
          <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQhsEwX6sxXnxt70pJXg1Rw/featured" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   var scroll_start = 0;
   var startchange = $('.menu_box');
   var offset = startchange.offset();
   $(document).scroll(function() {
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
          $('.menu_box').css('background-color', '#f8f8f8');
          $('.imglogo').css('width', '125px');
          $('.imglogo').css('height', '47.625px');
          $('.menu_box_ul a').css('font-size', '1.25rem');
          $('.menu_box_logo').css('padding', '10px 10px 10px 10px');
          $('.menu_box_ul').css('padding', '25px 0 10px 10px');
          $('.menu_box_ul_more.show a').css('font-size', '1.75rem');
          $('.menu_box_ul_more.show').css('padding-top', '80px');
       } else {
          $('.menu_box').css('background-color', 'transparent');
          $('.imglogo').css('width', '250px');
          $('.imglogo').css('height', '95.25px');
          $('.menu_box_ul a').css('font-size', '1.75rem');
          $('.menu_box_logo').css('padding', '20px');
          $('.menu_box_ul').css('padding', '40px 0 20px 20px');
          $('.menu_box_ul_more.show a').css('font-size', '2rem');
          $('.menu_box_ul_more.show').css('padding-top', '110px');
       }
   });
  });

  </script>
    
  <script>
  /* When the user clicks on the button,
  toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
  function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  }

  // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.icon')) {

      var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
    <script>
  // Get the modal
  var modal = document.getElementById('popupBoxOnePosition');
  var modal2 = document.getElementById('popupBoxTwoPosition');
  var modal3 = document.getElementById('popupBoxThreePosition');
  var modal4 = document.getElementById('popupBoxFourPosition');

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
          modal.style.display = "none";
      }
      if (event.target == modal2) {
          modal2.style.display = "none";
      }
      if (event.target == modal3) {
          modal3.style.display = "none";
      }
      if (event.target == modal4) {
          modal4.style.display = "none";
      }
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please try this- https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/zawHg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do that by `postMessage` like the following:

```
$('.close-modal').click(function(){
    $('.your-iframe')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
});
```

Comment: Can you put your code in `codepen` to test that online?

Comment: @Jokubas Fixed :).
 https://codepen.io/omidnikrah/pen/PdQwWv?editors=1000

Comment: The problem is you have 4 `iframe` and you set id only for first `iframe`. Now I set class for all of `iframe`

Comment: Okey it is very nice OmiD, but why this works only for first modal?

Comment: Okey I fix it just need to add different classes like iframe1, iframe2, iframe3 and so on. Thanks OmiD, but maybe you also know how to do then click on this <span onclick="document.getElementById('popupBoxOnePosition').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal1">&times;</span> also to stop playing video?

Comment: It's easy by the following code: 
$('.close').click(function() {
   $('.iframe1')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
});

Comment: Accept my answer if that help to you :)

Comment: Thanks best solutions :)

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('youriframe');
iframe.src = iframe.src;
```

This too

```
document.getElementById('some_frame_id').contentWindow.location.reload();
```

The second one will not work due to CORS in most cases.